# How to add Rich Snippets in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, google-rich-snippets

I have a script for rich snippets in json-ld. How to add those scripts to Product Page in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Implementation of Product schema
2. Implementing Aggregate schema
3. Implementation of Offer schema
4. Implementation of Product URL and SKU schema
5. Implementation of breadcrumbs schema
   You can see more example here: https://paulnrogers.com/guide-to-adding-rich-snippets-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 (2.3) already implemented rich snippets on Product Page (Offer and Aggregated Rating). Before add own snippets, you need remove old markup.

Add json-ld script you can in any product template, for example `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/additional.phtml`.

Native and essential RS (schemas) are described here: https://mirasvit.com/blog/magento-2-essential-rich-snippets.html